# Blue Prism: On entering a text in a text box, the adjacent button is not getting enabled

Tags: stage, blueprism

I am automating an enterprise application using Blue Prism, On entering a text in a particular text box, the button next to it should be enabled as per the process document which is happening when I do it manually. However, When I use write stage and enter the text its not happening.

I tried using navigate stage to click on the center of Textbox and used Application modeler to send keys within the same navigate stage.

Is there any way to achieve what I want?

Comment: What type of application are you working with? Browser/Win32?

Comment: Browser Application (IE browser)

Comment: After sending the keys, try sending a `{TAB}` key. Sometimes the scripts on webpages activate only after going out of focus of a particular html element.

Comment: I was able to solve it by embedding Javascript fragment and Invoking it through a Javascript function. Thank you all for your response.

Comment: Hi, i have same problem, can you also share the javascript fragment did you use please?

Comment: @Santosh Write the value in text box using `Global send key` or `Global send key event`. That should enable the button.

Answer (score 0):

Some elements are disabled until and unless user key strokes on one element. If you use write stage then it won't be get enabled.

For this, use the Global send key event to pass the value to text box only then the button will get enabled.

Give Global send key event the text parameter, while writing text to textbox it will generate key events.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Navigation Stage --> GlobalSendKeyEvents -->"{TAB}")
```

The app is probably waiting for a Javascript callback to tell the button it should be enabled. After youve set the data (probably with global send keys), I'd first recommend tabbing out of it, or clicking some other element on the page. Expirement with different combinations of  Focus, Tab, Activate, Click, etc, until you get lucky. Or, you can just look at the js and see if you can figure it out.